# Asp.Net Core 5 Docker container exit (1)

Tags: docker, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to run a docker container for my api application.  The application is asp.net mvc (.net core) 5.0.  I'm publishing the application to a /publish folder like:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish
```

The Dockerfile contains:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY publish/ app/
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AmaraCode.RainMaker.DataService.dll"]
```

To create the image I'm using:

```
docker build -t amaracodellc/dataservice .
```

To create the container I'm using:

```
docker run --name dataservice_rm --network="rm" --ip 192.168.0.40 -p 7601:80 -d amaracodellc/dataservice:latest
```

The container creates but exits immediately with Exit (1).  The log says:

```
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET program, but dotnet-AmaraCode.RainMaker.DataService.dll does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

I'm a bit stumped because the assembly name is correct since I copied it from the screen versus typing it in.  There are many messages on the web for Exit (1) but I can't seem to find one that helps in this case.

It is worth noting that I'm VERY new to Docker so I'm hoping someone here can see something that I'm not seeing.

Thanks in advance

Scott

Comment: Can you please share the whole dockerfile? I guess there is a `FROM` part in the beginning?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I had to press enter to get it to show.

Comment: To run an asp.net application, normally you use the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0`  image but it should work with both

Comment: did you publish your .net project first and then built the docker-image? if not, try that. Your error message says it tries to run `dotnet-AmaraCode.RainMaker.DataService.dll` but your dll seems to be `AmaraCode.RainMaker.DataService.dll` Did you change that and didnt rebuild your docker image?

Comment: I've tried to use mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 which is what I really wanted but when I do it gets Exit (145) and the log says:

Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You intended to execute a .NET program:
      The application 'AmaraCode.RainMaker.DataService.dll' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.
      Install a .NET SDK from:
        https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Comment: Here is my .Net version installed : 5.0.102

Comment: I'm not sure why it is putting -dotnet- on the front of my assembly name in the log.  I assumed it came from:
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AmaraCode.RainMaker.DataService.dll"]

Comment: ohhh i see what you did wrong, you switch the workdir to `/app` but then copy the files to `app/` which translates to `/app/app`. change this line to `COPY publish/ .` or COPY publish/ /app` and it should work

Comment: Im thinking that maybe the COPY isn't working when creating the image.  Is there a way to look into an image and verify the dll file is there?

Comment: yes you can use `RUN ls` to run ls during the build. You can also execute into the docker-image after the build by `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash maracodellc/dataservice:latest` and then freely navigate

Comment: You are the master my friend!  That was it and now it is working.  I'm very grateful!!!